# Allowing for muli-word search and not forcing the user to deliminate by comma

Tags: php, html

I am working on a small project with a few friends, and I am in charge of most of the PHP code. We currently have a semi-working website in which you can input recipe ingredients and find a full recipe to create.

The problem I am having currently is allowing the user to input multiple word ingredients (brown sugar, angel hair pasta, etc.) without forcing them to use a comma as a delimiter.

I am currently using every invalid character to delimit (spaces, commas, numbers, etc.), but that will only allow for 1 word ingredients to be searched.

I have thought about possibly creating an array of all the ingredients and checking to see if the user's input would match up to any of those and then pick them out, but I am not sure if that is the best solution.

Comment: Have you considered handling this in the UI and injecting commas before passing to PHP - something similar to how tags work on this site? You'd also get the benefit of auto-complete/intellisense

Comment: you could use array_intersect if you are matching against another array. the only thing to remember is that matching is case sensitive so you might want to do a array_map call with strtolower.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, do you think I could do that through javascript autocomplete and then just add a comma after every autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

How about a javascript based solution where there is a text box. When you begin to type, it pops up another text box below, suggesting that you can separate multiple ingredients. Name them "ingredients[]" so $_POST['ingredients'] is an array in php and you can iterate through them.

Easier solution is to do what you have done, separate by any spaces, comma, etc and just rank the search results by how many of the keywords match an ingredients list.